# switching layouts with angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I try to use ui-router for switching between different layouts

```
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  $stateProvider
    .state('root', {
      url: '/',
      views: {
        '@': {
          templateUrl: '_columnsTwo.html'   // 2 columns
        },
        'main@root': {
          templateUrl: 'content1.html',
          controller: 'homeCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('data', {
      url: '/du-lieu',
      parent: 'root',
      views: {
        'main': {
          templateUrl: 'content2.html',
          controller: 'dataCtrl'
        }
      }

    })
    .state('oneCol', {
      url: '/chi-tiet-tin',
      views: {
        '@': {
          templateUrl: '_columnsOne.html'   // one column layout
        },
        'detail@oneCol': {
          templateUrl: 'contentOneCol.html'
        }
      }    
    })    
});
```

Full code is at http://plnkr.co/edit/wGU6PaPAloCm33TDoGso?p=preview

Dont know why the state oneCol doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it is usually a typo, Check this updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/GygQZxEHogqcRS8vf1Bc?p=preview

The  **`templateUrl: 'contentOneCol.html'`** was calling a template - which did not exist:

```
.state('oneCol', {
  url: '/chi-tiet-tin',
  views: {
    '@': {
      templateUrl: '_columnsOne.html'   // one column layout
    },
    'detail@oneCol': {
      templateUrl: 'contentOneCol.html' // this file was not there
    }                                   // there was one with suffix '.hml'
  }    
})
```

Because the file in the plunker was named

```
contentOneCol.hml  // missing t
contentOneCol.html // correction I made
```